# Подстветка input. Jquery

Tags: html, jquery

Добрый вечер,вот мой `html code`

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#boughtamount").keyup(function() {
    var value = this.value;
    var price = 0;
    if (value > 100) {
      price = parseInt(value) * 1.25;
      $("#boughtamount").addClass("selectedgood");

    } else
      $("#boughtamount").addClass("selected");
    $('.res_sum').text(price);
  });
});
```

```css
.selected {
  border: 1px solid red
}

.selectedgood {
  border: 1px solid green
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form>
  <input type="number" placeholder="От 100 монет" id="boughtamount">
</form>
<div class="toPay">
  <p><i>К оплате:</i></p>
</div>
<div class="finalpriceforitem">
  <b><span class="res_sum">0</span>&nbsp;руб.</b>
</div>
```

Приведенный `jquery` код работает хорошо,но есть одна проблема. Когда пользователь вводит цифру `11`, то граница - `красная( это нормально)`, когда юзер напечатал `111` и более `(в качестве примере),то она становится зеленой`, но когда пользователь хочет ввести другую цену,например,`642`,то ему нужно стереть ранее введенные цифры, вот тут и появляется проблема. `input` всегда остается `(с зеленой границей)`.Как решить эту проблему?

Comment: cпасибо большое,подзабыл!

Answer (score 0):

```
} else {
  $("#boughtamount").removeClass("selectedgood");       
  $("#boughtamount").addClass("selected");   
}
```